# VS Code $Id$ line

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm working in a (C++) codebase where some files have headers from a legacy version control system. They end up looking something like this:

```
//--- some/source/file.cpp --------------------------------------*- C++ -*-==//
//
//               My Company's Library.
//
// Copyright My Company, 20xx
//
// $Id: abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789$
//===---------------------------------------------------------------------===//
```

In some files, the tag has a random-looking hex value in it. In other files, it just looks like `$Id$`. This is all vaguely annoying, but basically fine.

However, VS Code occasionally generates new `$Id$` lines. It will definitely fill in the hex value for files that don't have one, and I think I've seen it fill in the value for files even if they already have a hex value. I'd prefer it didn't do this, as it pollutes Git diffs. I also want to understand what's going on here. Why is VS Code changing these lines, and how can I stop it?

Comment: most likely it has to do with your version control

Comment: I'm using Git, which doesn't have these kinds of tags. Older versions of the codebase used older version control, but nobody I work with seems to know. But either way, why would VS Code make edits to it?

Comment: It turns out that there were some settings in my .gitattributes file that were causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is controlled by the `ident` in the `.gitattributes` file.

See the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes):

> `ident`
>
> When the attribute `ident` is set for a path, Git replaces `$Id$` in the blob object with `$Id:`, followed by the 40-character hexadecimal blob object name, followed by a dollar sign `$` upon checkout. Any byte sequence that begins with `$Id:` and ends with `$` in the worktree file is replaced with `$Id$` upon check-in.